# If $P(x^{\beta})-P(x)=Q(x^{\alpha})-Q(x)$ then $P(x)=R(x^{\alpha})-R(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $\alpha\geq2$ and $\beta\geq2$ two integers such that for every $a>0,\; b>0$ we have $\alpha^a\neq \beta^b.$ Let $P(x)=\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^i,\;a_i\in\mathbb{C}$ and $Q(x)=\sum_{i=1}^mb_ix^i,\;b_i\in\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$P(x^{\beta})-P(x)=Q(x^{\alpha})-Q(x).$$

Show that there exists $R(x)$ s.t. $P(x)=R(x^{\alpha})-R(x).$

@ Ewan Delanoy gives me a very nice idea (that is written below) but we have a problem with the proof that
$(W_2+W_3)\cap V_{\beta}=\lbrace 0 \rbrace.$

Can you help us?

Comment: Where does this exercise come from ? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I tried to find some relation between the coefficients but it is very hard to write them explicitely.

Comment: sorry there was a mistake

Comment: Comparing degrees shows that $\alpha m=\beta n$, for starters.

Comment: Yes, there isalso some simple relation as $a_n=b_m$ but this is not enough

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP is asking for hints, I intentionally do not provide a full solution.

**Quick hint :** View $V={\mathbb C}[X]$ as a $\mathbb C$-vector space. The map $\phi_{\alpha} : V\to V, P \mapsto P(X^{\alpha})-P(X)$ is a linear endomorphism of $V$. Denote its image by $V_{\alpha}$. The hint is : compute a basis for $V_{\alpha}\cap V_{\beta}$.

If that hint is not enough, try

**More detailed hint :**

> We can assume $\alpha<\beta$ (why?). Let $g=\gcd(\alpha,\beta)$ and $\alpha'=\frac{\alpha}{g},\beta'=\frac{\beta}{g}$. Next, define the following subsets of $V$ : ${\cal F}_1=\Bigg\lbrace \phi_{\alpha}(X^{\beta k}-X^{k}) \ \Bigg| \ k\geq 1\Bigg\rbrace, {\cal F}_2=\Bigg\lbrace \phi_{\alpha}(X^k) \ \Bigg| \ k\geq 1, \beta'\not| k \Bigg\rbrace$, ${\cal F}_3=\Bigg\lbrace \phi_{\alpha}(X^{\beta'k}) \ \Bigg| \ k\geq 1, g\not| k \Bigg\rbrace$. For each $i=1,2,3$, denote by $W_i$ the subspace spanned by ${\cal F}_i$. Show (in that order) that $V_{\alpha}=W_1+W_2+W_3$, $(W_2+W_3)\cap V_{\beta}=\lbrace 0 \rbrace, V_{\alpha}\cap V_{\beta}=W_1$.

Comment: I'm not able to prove the third equality, i.e $V_\alpha\cap V_\beta=W_1,$ can you help me?

Comment: @bojica   The third equality follows from the first two (and the easy fact that $W_1 \subseteq V_{\alpha}\cap V_{\beta}$).

Comment: But the first two equalities give to me the incorrect inclusion (the trivial one): $V_{\alpha}\cap V_{\beta}=(W_1+W_2+W_3)\cap V_{\beta}\supseteq (W_1\cap V_{\beta})+((W_2+W_3)\cap V_{\beta})=W_1$

Comment: @bojica You can prove the other inclusion as follows : let $v\in V_{\alpha}\cap V_{\beta}$. Then $v\in V_{\alpha}$, so $v=w_1+w_2+w_3$ with $w_i\in W_i$. Then $w_2+w_3=v-w_1 \in V_{\beta}$ since $v$ and $w_1$ are both in $V_{\beta}$. By $(W_2+W_3)\cap V_{\beta}=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, we deduce $w_2+w_3=0$ and $v=w_1\in W_1$.

Comment: Another question: when I want to show that $(W_2+W_3)\cap V_{\beta}=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ i proced like that: I consider 2 different case, if $x^{k\beta}=x^{h\alpha}$ then I found a contradiction, if $x^{k\beta}=x^{h\beta'\alpha}$ then I'm not able to find a contradiction. Can you help me?

Comment: @bojica a $w\in W_2+W_3$ can be written $w=\sum_{j}\lambda_j\phi_{\alpha}(X^{j})+\sum_{k}\mu_k\phi_{\alpha}(X^{\beta'k})$. If $w$ is in $V_{\beta}$, so is $w'=w-\sum_{k}\mu_k\phi_{\beta}(X^{\alpha'k})$. Now $w'=\sum_{j}\lambda_j\phi_{\alpha}(X^{j})+\sum_{k}\mu_k(\phi_{\alpha}(X^{\beta'k})-\phi_{\beta}(X^{\alpha'k}))$, and all the terms in this sum are polynomials who are either zero or whose degree is not divisible by $\beta$ ; further all those degrees are distinct. So the sum can only be in $V_{\beta}$ when all the terms are zero.

Comment: The degree are $\alpha j $ and $\beta 'k$. Why they can't be equal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58375/discussion-between-ewan-delanoy-and-bojica).